# Issue in Compiling gradle File

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-appcompat

It is my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.0 rc2'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.nanu.admin.notification"
            minSdkVersion 8
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    }
```

the last two lines showing errors ..how can I solve that in android studio???

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your build version of the project and support version are different change the support library versions

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the support **libraries v23**, you have to compile **with api 23.**

Change this line :

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
```

Also change the  `buildToolsVersion` with the latest stable release.

```
 buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here

```
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0 rc2'
```

**Solution : 1**

replace builtToolsVersion with 23.0.1 or 23.0.2

**Solution : 2**

replace

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

with

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

or

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```